# Cannot call an action function from an action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Unfortunately, I am unable to call handleApiErrors from inside the catch error block. The function is not called, the line of code handleApiErrors(error, 'Data could not be retrieved')  is ignored)

The double use of dispatch seems to be causing the problem but according to the thunk docs it should work

```
const getInitialData = () => (dispatch) => {
    getBookList()
        .then((books) => {
            dispatch(fetchBooksSuccess(books));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            handleApiErrors(error, 'Data could not be retrieved') 
        });
    };


const handleApiErrors = (error, userMessage = '') => (dispatch) => {
    const { response, message } = error;
    let errorMessage = '';
    switch (response.status) {
        case 401:
            errorMessage = 'You are not authenticated';
            break;
        case 403:
            errorMessage = 'You are not authorized to access this ressource';
            break;
        case 500:
            errorMessage = `${userMessage} There was an internal error, please try again`;
            break;
        case 503:
            errorMessage = `${userMessage} The network connection is unavailable at the moment`;
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = message;
     }
     dispatch(setApiErrors(errorMessage));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actions should be simple functions returning.

```
dispatch(handleApiErrors(error, 'Data could not be retrieved'));


const handleApiErrors = (error, userMessage = '') => {
const { response, message } = error;
let errorMessage = '';
switch (response.status) {
    case 401:
        errorMessage = 'You are not authenticated';
        break;
    case 403:
        errorMessage = 'You are not authorized to access this ressource';
        break;
    case 500:
        errorMessage = `${userMessage} There was an internal error, please try again`;
        break;
    case 503:
        errorMessage = `${userMessage} The network connection is unavailable at the moment`;
        break;
    default:
        errorMessage = message;
 }
 setApiErrors(errorMessage);
};
```

Comment: oh yes thank you, I forgot the dispatch, but actually following your advice moved this action to a helper function, since it is too complex for an action